# tailwind css file is not working and giving errors

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

please someone help me with these three warnings
i am working with react.js + vite
i have tried everything but nothing works

i have tried everything and nothing work please help me to connect the file with my
app.jsx

Comment: `warn` is not not the same as `error`